# How to delete a subarray with a specific number of elements

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array:

```
arr = [["csb#"], ["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"], ["spl#"]]
```

How do I delete subarrays that contain only one element, like `["csb#"]`?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Array#delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) method:

```
> arr.delete_if{|e| e.size == 1}
#=> [["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"]]
```

Note: this will modify your original array by deleting the sub-array which contains only 1 element.

```
> arr
#=> [["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"]]
```

If you just want to fetch the sub-array which contains more than one element:

[`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) :

```
 > arr.select{|a| a.size  > 1}
 #=> [["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"]]
```

or:

[`Array#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) :

```
> arr.reject{|a| a.size  <= 1}
#=> [["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:

```
arr.reject {|e| e[1..-1].empty? }
=> [["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"]]
```

The following solutions work if you are sure that your array *doesn't contain booleans on nils*:

```
arr.map { |f, s, *o| [f, s, *o] if s }.compact
```

Or even:

```
arr.map { |e| e if e[1] }.compact
```

Or almost the same with `select` (thanks @engineersmnky):

```
arr.select { |a| a[1] }
```

Comment: Using a conditional like `if s` in `map` forces you to use `compact` to remove the nil values. Instead, `select` or `reject` prior to `map`. Having to clean up the resulting array is an indicator that something was not done correctly.

Comment: @theTinMan, I appreciate your notes, but this is just-for-fun solution since pretty clear and right answer already  had been done.

Comment: Perhaps you suggested it in fun, however we see people using that seriously in answers and questions, and it results in others thinking its appropriate or preferable over doing it right in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject). With `!` it will mutate the original array, otherwise will return a new array:

```
arr =[["csb#"], ["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"], ["spl#"]]
arr.reject {|e| e.length == 1 }
#=> [["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"]]
arr.reject! {|e| e.length == 1 }
#=> [["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"]]
arr
#=> [["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"]]
```

[`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select), or `select!`, also can be used for the same functionality:

```
arr = [["csb#"], ["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"], ["spl#"]]
#=> [["csb#"], ["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"], ["spl#"]]
arr.select! {|e| e.length != 1 }
#=> [["gcp30", "hdd"], ["gcp30", "hdd", "30", "no"]]
```

Comment: As a note the last solution will also output an empty array since `length != 1` although technically this still satisfies the question of *"How to delete subarrays that contain only one element eg. ["csb#"]"*